# Scala return does not return

Tags: scala, recursion, return

There is some misunderstanding between me and Scala

**0 or 1?**

```
object Fun extends App {

 def foo(list:List[Int], count:Int = 0): Int = {

    if (list.isEmpty) { // when this is true
      return 1   // and we are about to return 1, the code goes to the next line
    }

    foo(list.tail, count + 1) // I know I do not use "return here" ...

    count
  }

  val result = foo( List(1,2,3) )

  println ( result ) // 0

}
```

1. Why does it print 0?
2. Why does recursion work even without "return"
   (when it is in the middle of function, but not in the end)?
3. Why doesn't it return 1? when I use "return" explicitly?

**--- EDIT:**

It will work if I use `return` here `"return foo(list.tail, count + 1)'`.
Bu it does NOT explain (for me) why "return 1" does not work above.

Comment: To your EDIT: see the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: What are you trying to do? or what is your expected output?

Comment: @Hiura For me your last sentence is more valuable than first. That leads me to the simple rule like: *"last line wins"* in terms of returning the value. But this not quite true because "return foo()" would win, event hough it is not last.

Comment: @ses as long as it helps you I'm happy! ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you read my full explanation below then the answers to your three questions should all be clear, but here's a short, explicit summary for everyone's convenience:

1. **Why does it print 0?** This is because the method call was returning `count`, which had a default value of `0`—so it returns `0` and you print `0`. If you called it with `count=5` then it would print `5` instead. (See the example using `println` below.)
2. **Why does recursion work even without "return" (when it is in the middle of function, but not in the end)?** You're making a recursive call, so the recursion happens, but you weren't returning the result of the recursive call.
3. **Why doesn't it return 1? when I use "return" explicitly?** It does, but only in the case when `list` is empty. If `list` is non-empty then it returns `count` instead. (Again, see the example using `println` below.)

---

Here's a quote from *Programming in Scala* by Odersky (the first edition is available online):

> The recommended style for methods is in fact to avoid having explicit, and especially multiple, return statements. Instead, think of each method as an expression that yields one value, which is returned. This philosophy will encourage you to make methods quite small, to factor larger methods into multiple smaller ones. On the other hand, design choices depend on the design context, and Scala makes it easy to write methods that have multiple, explicit returns if that's what you desire. [[link]](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/classes-and-objects.html#i119623890-1)

In Scala you very rarely use the `return` keyword, but instead take advantage that everything in an *expression* to propagate the return value back up to the top-level expression of the method, and that result is then used as the return value. You can think of `return` as something more like `break` or `goto`, which disrupts the normal control flow and might make your code harder to reason about.

Scala doesn't have statements like Java, but instead everything is an *expression*, meaning that everything returns a value. That's one of the reasons why Scala has `Unit` instead of `void`—because even things that would have been `void` in Java need to return a value in Scala. Here are a few examples about how expressions work that are relevant to your code:

1. Things that are expressions in Java act the same in Scala. That means the result of `1+1` is `2`, and the result of `x.y()` is the return value of the method call.
2. Java has if *statements*, but Scala has if *expressions*. This means that the Scala `if`/`else` construct acts more like the [Java ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a#Java). Therefore, `if (x) y else z` is equivalent to `x ? y : z` in Java. A lone `if` like you used is the same as `if (x) y else Unit`.
3. A code block in Java is a statement made up of a group of statements, but in Scala it's an expression made up of a group of expressions. A code block's result is the result of the last expression in the block. Therefore, the result of { o.a(); o.b(); o.c() } is whatever `o.c()` returned. You can make similar constructs with [the comma operator in C/C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator): `(o.a(), o.b(), o.c())`. Java doesn't really have anything like this.
4. The `return` keyword breaks the normal control flow in an expression, causing the current method to immediately return the given value. You can think of it kind of like throwing an exception, both because it's an exception to the normal control flow, and because (like the `throw` keyword) the resulting expression has type `Nothing`. The `Nothing` type is used to indicate an expression that never returns a value, and thus can essentially be ignored during type inference. Here's simple example showing that `return` has the result type of `Nothing`:

```
def f(x: Int): Int = {
  val nothing: Nothing = { return x }
  throw new RuntimeException("Can't reach here.")
}
```

Based on all that, we can look at your method and see what's going on:

```
 def foo(list:List[Int], count:Int = 0): Int = { 
   // This block (started by the curly brace on the previous line
   // is the top-level expression of this method, therefore its result
   // will be used as the result/return value of this method.
     if (list.isEmpty) {
       return 1 // explicit return (yuck)
     }
     foo(list.tail, count + 1) // recursive call
     count // last statement in block is the result
  }
```

Now you should be able to see that `count` is being used as the result of your method, except in the case when you break the normal control flow by using `return`. You can see that the `return` is working because `foo(List(), 5)` returns `1`. In contrast, `foo(List(0), 5)` returns `5` because it's using the result of the block, `count`, as the return value. You can see this clearly if you try it:

```
println(foo(List()))      // prints 1 because list is empty
println(foo(List(), 5))   // prints 1 because list is empty
println(foo(List(0)))     // prints 0 because count is 0 (default)
println(foo(List(0), 5))  // prints 5 because count is 5
```

You should restructure your method so that the value that the body is an expression, and the return value is just the result of that expression. It looks like you're trying to write a method that returns the number of items in the list. If that's the case, this is how I'd change it:

```
 def foo(list:List[Int], count:Int = 0): Int = {
   if (list.isEmpty) count
   else foo(list.tail, count + 1)
 }
```

When written this way, in the base case (list is empty) it returns the current item count, otherwise it returns the result of the recursive call on the list's tail with `count+1`.

If you *really* want it to always return `1` you can change it to `if (list.isEmpty) 1` instead, and it will always return `1` because the base case will always return `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning the value of `count` from the first call (that is, `0`), not the value from the recursive call of foo.

To be more precise, in you code, you don't use the returned value of the recursive call to foo.

Here is how you can fix it:

```
def foo(list:List[Int], count:Int = 0): Int = {

    if (list.isEmpty) {
        1
    } else {
        foo(list.tail, count + 1)
    }
}
```

This way, you get `1`.

By the way, don't use `return`. It doesn't do always what you would expect.

In Scala, a function return implicitly the last value. You don't need to explicitly write `return`.

Comment: Yeah.. but why it does not do what I'm expecting? I thought that return is return.

Comment: I added a quick explanation but you should probably start with a good tutorial. E.g. http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-for-java-programmers.html

Comment: I read this all. But thanks. This is not a lack of reading but lack of trying.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you do not have a return in front of foo(list.tail, count + 1) means that, after you return from the recursion, execution is falling through and returning count. Since 0 is passed as a default value for count, once you return from all of the recursed calls, your function is returning the original value of count.

You can see this happening if you add the following println to your code:

```
def foo(list:List[Int], count:Int = 0): Int = {

     if (list.isEmpty) { // when this is true
        return 1   // and we are about to return 1, the code goes to the next line
     }

    foo(list.tail, count + 1) // I know I do not use "return here" ...

     println ("returned from foo " + count)
     count
}
```

To fix this you should add a return in front of foo(list.tail.....).

Answer (score 1):

Your `return` works, just not the way you expect because you're ignoring its value. If you were to pass an empty list, you'd get 1 as you expect.
Because you're not passing an empty list, your original code works like this:

- `foo` called with List of 3 elements and count 0 (call this recursion 1)
- list is not empty, so we don't get into the block with `return`
- we recursively enter `foo`, now with 2 elements and count 1 (recursion level 2)
- list is not empty, so we don't get into the block with `return`
- we recursively enter `foo`, now with 1 element and count 2 (recursion level 3)
- list is not empty, so we don't get into the block with `return`
- we now enter `foo` with no elements and count 3 (recursion level 4)
- we enter the block with `return` and return 1
- we're back to recursion level 3. The result of the call to `foo` from which we just came back in neither assigned nor returned, so it's ignored. We proceed to the next line and return count, which is the same value that was passed in, 2
- the same thing happens on recursion levels 2 and 1 - we ignore the return value of `foo` and instead return the original `count`
- the value of `count` on the recursion level 1 was 0, which is the end result

Comment: hard to follow but I guess this is quite true. If speaking of simple rule "do not use return, and use if() {} else " ?

Comment: There's no rule for if/else - that's just a style. The last statement in a method will be the return value.

Comment: Got it. The deal in the recursion. That was simple (sadly).

Answer (score 0):

you return count in your program which is a constant and is initialized with 0, so that is what you are returning at the top level of your recursion.